# Running Django Project with config Folder in Pycharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I am currently trying my hand at simple Django development. I went through a small tutorial with great success, but this time, I wanted something a bit more challenging. However, now I am having some difficulty setting up my Django project with the 'Two Scoops for Django' layout.

Previously, the default for Pycharm's Django template was more than to suit my needs. When it would generate, I would get the following files:

```
project
   /site
      __init__.py
      settings.py
      urls.py
      wsgi.py 
   /templates
   manage.py
```

With that simple setup, I am able to do all that I need within Pycharm's Tool section (specifically Run manage.py Task and the Python Console).

This time, I wanted to follow a more formal project layout, the one used in 'Two Scoops of Django'. So, I created a new project, added the directories that were missing, **removed the settings.py file**, added the setting files (`__init__`.py, base.py, and local.py within the config directory), and copied the contents of what was within the settings.py file into the base.py file (for now anyway).

Currently, my layout is now the following:

```
project
   /docs
   /site
      /config
         /settings
            __init__.py
            base.py
            local.py
      /static
      /media
      /templates
      __init__.py
      urls.py
      wsgi.py
   manage.py
```

Unlike the default project layout where I can simply go to Tools and run manage.py Task, I no longer have that option available to me.

I am also having difficulty just trying to run the manage.py with the appropriate settings from the Python/Django Console within Pycharm.

I imagine it is entirely due to not being configured properly. I just haven't seen any recommendations or tutorials fixing this issue.

I tried searching for setting up a Django project in Pycharm with this particular project layout, but either they do not have any information on it, or I am simply not using the correct vocabulary (more than likely, that is the issue).

Furthermore, when I run the Django Python/Console, I am greeted with the following error:

> ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting LOGGING_CONFIG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

I tried googling that, but I didn't seem to find a clear answer to my particular issue. In my previous project, I could at least run simple commands.

Obviously, I am very new to configuring a Django project, let alone with Pycharm (the easiest IDE available for me). I would just like to get to a point where I can start writing code again.

Comment: Are you using `virutalenv`?

Comment: Did you read the error message you get?

Comment: Hopefully my edit with help clarify some things for you. I am new to setting up configurations with Django, but hopefully this should help find the issue ;) .

Comment: But the thing is, it is defined, in both manage.py and wsgi.py. I even changed the default module from mysite.settings to mysite.config.settings (in one and both locations).

I would run manage.py with the appropriate settings, but that doesn't work as well (using the command manage.py shell --settings=multipletest.settings.local), but it simply barks invalid syntax at this point.

I also tried using settings.configure() in my manage.py file.

I know it it seems trivial and obvious to you, but I'm a noob at this stuff. I wouldn't have asked unless I honestly tried myself.

Answer (score 1):

Try this from your console:
`python manage.py runserver --settings=site.config.settings.local` or add `--settings=site.config.settings.local` to your script parameters in PyCharm run configuration.

Comment: Also, it is not `mysite.config.settings`, it is `mysite.config.settings.local` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

According https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/settings/#designating-the-settings you should add

> --settings=mysite.settings

to Additional options of Debug Configurations
or add settings.configure() to your python script (after from django.conf import settings)